# How to see data written to a file?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to troubleshoot a program that seems to fail when saving files. Using ProcMon from SysInternals I was able to determine that it writes a log file somewhere, but right after it fails, it deletes it. So, it all happens in milliseconds and I can't get to see the file.

Is there anything for Windows that would allow me to see the actual data written to the files? I tried DiskMon but does not show data as well.

EDIT: The specifics of the program I am trying to work with is [SAI (Easy Paint Tool)](http://www.systemax.jp/en/sai/), trying to troubleshoot some saving issues.

Comment: is it a text log file or something else?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, it is a text log this program generates. Seems to be XML as well. (I've only been able to recover parts of it and found mixed stuff -- probably from the recovery itself)

Comment: Idea (no time to formulate into a full answer, and not sure it'll work): create the log file manually beforehand, then deny yourself (or whatever user the program runs as) delete permissions on the file. Ideally it'll just append its data to the file, then fail to delete it, but it might also fail to write at all because the file already exists, or decide to write to a different file instead.

Comment: You could attach a debugger and step through to the file write, then normally open up the file, read it before it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If the log is present while the program is running normally, and the drive it's on is NTFS, create a hardlink to the log. (If you have nothing else, a hardlink can be created using fsutil on XP or mklink on Vista+.)

Comment: I can't do that beforehand, right? The log is created at the moment I start the sae action, and the log is deleted at the moment that fails (does not make sense to me). I only have milliseconds where the file is actually there.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either, which is why I couldn't believe it. :) Can't really think of anything simple, but at an extreme, I could patch ANSICON so it would log all WriteFile data (not just console). What's the program?

Comment: It's sai.exe, the executable file for SAI, an image edition program. Turns out that it can open PSD (Photoshop) files but suddenly started failing when saving those it its own format. I'm trying to troubleshoot that and found that it creates the destination file with a temp name, then a log file in ProgramData and then deletes both.

Comment: If it's version 1.1.0, use a hex editor (or something) to search for 1C D1 4B 00 and replace with 24 D1 4B 00 - that replaces the delete function with another.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and report results. What should this new function do?

Comment: It just gets the attributes, instead (specifically, DeleteFileA becomes GetFileAttributesA, preserving the arguments). There are 15 in total, didn't bother tracking down the specific one(s).

Comment: Took me ages (sorry about that) but I finally tried that and it worked like a charm. Unfortunately, the information dumped there is not useful to me, but it did solve the original question I had. If you want to add it to your answer I could mark it as the answer for this question. I will add the specifics of this program into the question.